# How to use weight with the package "crsosstable" for R

Tags: crosstable

The crosstable package give me exactly what I need to do some exploratory work in a data set composed of answers to a survey. But I need to weight the crosstabulation  to get a representative results of the population I'm studying. Any ideas how I could use weights with this package?

So far I have used the "survey" package to do that, but it's lacking presentation tool to get publication ready tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the dev of the `crosstable` package and it is unfortunately not supporting weights yet.

I would love to implement this as a feature one day, so you should definitely open a Feature Request on [GitHub](https://github.com/DanChaltiel/crosstable/issues/new/choose).

As I've never had to do a weighted description myself, please add a simplified version of your use case so that I can make something useful to everyone.